# CustomTableViewCell is not connecting to my ViewController

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to use my own tableViewCell, because I want more than one subtitle on the cell. I made a file with Cocoa Touch Class, and I modified it to include the labels. When I try and use it in my view controller I get an error saying that my custom class is undefined.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)-> UITableView {
        let textFieldCell = UINib(nibName: "CustomTableViewCell", bundle: nil)
        self.tableView.register(textFieldCell,forCellReuseIdentifier: "CustomTableViewCell")
   ***     let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier:"CustomTableViewCell") as? CustomTableViewCell 
        if searching {
            cell.schoolName = searchCollege[indexPath.row]
            }
        else{

            .... other stuff
        }
        return cell
       }
```

It throws an error by the stars,"Use of undeclared type 'CustomTableViewCell'", thanks!

Cell class is called `class CustomTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {`

Comment: Never register cells in `cellForRow`, do it once in `viewDidLoad`. By the way extra XIBs are only useful if the cell is used in multiple table or collection views.

Comment: what is the name of your cell class ? also please let me know the identifier

Comment: Okay I put it in, let me know if there is anything else you want to know @NavneetKaur

Answer (score 0):

Add this method inn your `viewDidLoad()` function

```
tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "CustomTableViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "CustomTableViewCell")
```

Comment: The program is still giving me the same error, "use of undeclared type CustomTableViewCell "

Answer (score 0):

We dont need Register Cell every time, Write that line in View didLoad Method

```
override func viewDidLoad()
{
    super.viewDidLoad()


    let cellNib = UINib(nibName: "CustomTableViewCell", bundle: nil)
    tblView.register(cellNib, forCellReuseIdentifier: "CustomTableViewCell")

    tblView.rowHeight = CGFloat(UITableViewAutomaticDimension)
    tblView.estimatedRowHeight = 50

}
```

And Use that in call for row method

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
 {
    let simpleTableIdentifier = "CustomTableViewCell"

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: simpleTableIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! CustomTableViewCell

    return cell
}
```